# Interactive plotting mode pl.ion() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have the following in my `matplotlibrc`:

```
backend : QT4Agg
backend.qt4 : PySide
```

If I try the following:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.ion()
pl.plot(xrange(10))
pl.show()
pl.draw()
```

Nothing happens. No window is opened.

**But** if I do:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.ioff()
pl.plot(xrange(10))
pl.show()
```

I can see the window and the plot correctly.

Ho can I fix this? I am using [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)'s distribution on Linux 64 bit.

### Update:

I have reproduced the behavior above in two different ways:

1. From the shell (e.g. bash), `> python program.py`
2. Starting `ipython` as `> ipython`, and then `run program.py`

Comment: are you running this through an interactive shell?

Comment: @tcaswell No shell. Just running it as `python program.py`.

Comment: interactive mode does not work if you are not in an interactive shell.

Comment: see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2503

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell I have also reproduced the behavior by starting `ipython`, i.e. `> ipython` and then `run program.py`. Doesn't `ipython` start as an interactive shell?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used to be able to do interactive plotting with `plt.ion()` and no trouble, until recently when it just stopped working. My situation was similar to yours: I could plot still images when not using plt.ion().

I didn't get any error message, but the plot just didn't show. The program ran fine in every other way.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and recently installed QT4, which I suspect has something to do with it.

I googled around, learned about backends and found the following which solves the problem for me

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "WXAgg"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I previously had QT4Agg as shown by
    `print matplotlib.get_backend()`

Comment: I tried this, but did not work for me. :( I have Python 3.9.2, matplotlib 3.3.4 and wxPython 4.1.1.